# Definition of the quotient curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Given a smooth projective curve $C$ such that a group $G$ acts on it, how exactly is the quotient curve ${X/G}$ defined? I cannot seem to find any resources covering explicitly it's definition. I am aware of the fact that there are various categorical equivalences between geometrical objects (varieties) and algebraic objects (function fields) and maybe these are at work here, but I'm uncertain

Comment: There is a set of properties a quotient $X/G$ should have if it exists (it should be "universal" in a certain sense), and then one tries to construct a scheme $\pi: X \rightarrow Y$ with "these" properties. In many cases such a quotient does not exist.

Comment: The projective line $C:=\mathbb{P}^1$ may be constructed as a quotient $U/\mathbb{G}_m$ where $\mathbb{G}_m$ is the group-scheme of units. Any invertible sheaf on $C$ may be constructed using a character of $\mathbb{G}_m$  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4599310/a-description-of-line-bundles-on-projective-spaces-mathcalo-mathbbpn/4601133#4601133

Comment: By this I mean the following: There is an algebraic vector bundle of rank one $\pi: L(d) \rightarrow C$ with sheaf of sections $\mathcal{O}(d)$. The vector bundle $L(d)$ is constructed using a character of $\mathbb{G}_m$.

Comment: If you have a group $G$ acting on a set $S$ it follows the "quotient" $S/G$ is by definition the set of equivalence classes, and if $S$ has a topology you get an induced topology on $S/G$ such that the natural map $\pi: S \rightarrow S/G$ is continuous. If you want to do this for schemes there are many problems involved. You want a scheme $\pi:X \rightarrow X/G$ where the "points" of $X/G$ correspond 1-1 to the orbits of $X$ under $G$. To construct such quotients is a non-trivial problem in algebraic geometry (called "geometric invariant theory").

Comment: @hm2020 thank you very much for your comments. I have to admit I'm not familiar with scheme theory, the extent of my knowledge is essentially just basic Algebraic Geometry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to define a quotient of a curve $C$ under the action of the finite group $G$ is as the curve with function field $K(C)^G$, the $G$-invariants of the function field $K(C)$ under the action of $G$. This works because the categories of regular curves over a base field $k$ with nonconstant morphisms and finitely generated field extensions of $k$ with transcendence degree one are [canonically equivalent](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BY1). To see that $K(X)^G$ is again a function field, note that $[K(X)^G:K(X)]$ is a finite Galois extension of degree $|G|$ - so $K(X)^G$ is again of transcendence degree one. For the claim that $K(X)^G$ is again finitely generated, see [here on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21086/when-are-intersections-of-finitely-generated-field-extensions-finitely-generated).

There are other ways: if $G$ is finite, then we can cover $X$ by $G$-invariant affine opens (take an affine open neighborhood $U$ of $x\in X$ and consider $\bigcap_{g\in G} gU$ which is open since $G$ is finite and affine as $X$ is separated) and compute the quotient on each of these affine pieces, then glue back together, using that for an affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec} R$, the quotient by $G$ is $\operatorname{Spec} R^G$.

Comment: I'm not sure why you got downvoted. Just a question, though: how do we know also that ${K(X)^G}$ is also an algebraic function field of transcendence degree $1$? Thank you

Comment: @CoffeeBean I've added a little material to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect. I was a little confused how you knew that ${K(X) / K(X)^G}$ would be a Galois extension, but I found out on the Wikipedia page that an equivalent formulation of a field extension ${E/F}$ being Galois is that $F$ is the fixed field of $F$ under some finite subgroup ${G \leq \text{Aut}(E)}$. Thank you!